# Ubuntu install erase disk fails

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install `Ubuntu 15.04` on my computer but it fails. I used Win 8.1 before on that `SSD`. My pc starts the installer in `UEFI mode`. The installer says that there is no other OS on my pc and then I choose the Erase disk and install Ubuntu option, but a few moments later this error message appears:

```
The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.
```

I have tried to create partition by myself but I got other error messages.

My pc

- AMD FX8150
- ram: kingston hyperX 2400Mhz
- ram: kingston hyperX 2400Mhz
- Sapphire radeon  hd7770
- SSD: OCZ Agility 3 240Gb
- MB: Gigabyte 970A-UD3P

Answer (score 1):

1. Select `try ubuntu before you install`
2. Open `gparted`
3. Delete every partition on your hard drive, then click apply changes.
4. Restart your computer, you will now be able to create partitions